# @OneToMany relationship with Composite key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, composite-key

I have the following model (ignoring irrelevant/obvious code, like setters and getters):

```
@Entity
public class Invoice {
    @Id // sequence generated
    private Long invoiceId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoiceId", referencedColumnName = "invoiceId")
    @OrderBy("id.itemNumber")
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}


@Entity
public class Item {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemPK id;
}


@Embeddable
public class ItemPK {
    private Long invoiceId;
    private Long itemNumber;
}
```

Can't change the DB structure, as it's a legacy DB :(

The itemNumber is basically an index that starts at zero.

If I take an existing Invoice and just remove the existing item and add 2 new items in the list, when trying to update the Invoice object I run into all sorts of problems:

If I leave the ItemPK null, I get:
***org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object is an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before merging***

If I try to fill the values of ItemPK myself (the id of the invoice and the index), I get: ***org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session*** (there already is an invoice item in the DB and it has the invoice id and the index = 0, just like the first object in my new list of items).

If I try to leave the invoiceId null (in the ItemPK object), I get: ***java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("Item"."invoiceId")***

Is there anyway to let Hibernate/JPA handle this ?
Or do I need to completely remove the association, defined the list as @Transient and just fill it and save it in my service classes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively have a bidirectional association here, since the invoiceId in the Item entity is in fact a foreign key to the Invoice. You should thus map the association as a bidirectional one, and use the [`@MapsId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) annotation. Its javadoc has an example.

Comment: i have a similar problem and tried to use this but couldn't get it to work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600142/how-to-define-onetomany-in-parent-entity-when-child-has-composite-pk